# SCSS mixin for displaying class or id before element name

Tags: sass, mixins

My mixin has 4 variables: Items per row, gutter, child element name, prefix type

For instance

```
// 4 per row, 25 gutter, element name, and it's a class
@include list-grid(4, 25, list__item, class);
```

Mixin:

```
 @mixin list-grid($per-row, $spacing, $child, $prefix){
    margin: 0 em(-$spacing/2);
    @include clearfix;
    //negate the display-inline biatch
    letter-spacing: -0.31em;

        >   @if $prefix == "class" { 
                .#{$child}
            }
            @elseif $prefix == "id" { 
                ##{$child}
            }
            @else $prefix == null { 
                #{$child}
            }


            width: 100%/$per-row;
            font-size: 16px;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 em($spacing/2) em($spacing) em($spacing/2);
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            background-clip: content-box;
        }
}
```

I thought that I could use some if statements to change the output CSS to use the prefix the user sets or if nothing is set to not include a prefix.

Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you need to put the selector into a variable:

```
  $selector: $child;

  @if $prefix == "class" { 
      $selector: '.#{$child}';
  }
  @elseif $prefix == "id" { 
      $selector: '##{$child}';
  }

  > #{$selector} {
    color: red;
  }
```

However, you're over-engineering.  Just pass in the selector you want to use.

```
list-grid($per-row, $spacing, $selector) {
    > #{$selector} {
        color: red;
    }
}

.foo {
    @include list-grid(1, 1, '#foo');
}

.bar {
    @include list-grid(1, 1, '.bar');
}

ul {
    @include list-grid(1, 1, 'li');
}
```

Comment: Thanks — I did think it's a little over engineered, but appreciated both parts!